# Splitting pandas DataFrame conditionally in two groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to split the dataset into two groups based on whether the value in the last row of that column is bigger than 0.

To illustrate:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkVb6.png)

This allows me to split the 1,000 clients into two groups.

```
pivot_data_credit = data.pivot_table(values='nr_credit_applications', index='yearmonth', columns=['client_nr'])

pivot_data_credit.loc[:,'Credit Total'] = pivot_data_credit.sum(axis=1)

pivot_data_credit.loc['TotalRow'] = pivot_data_credit.sum()
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mask with `iloc` along the last row and use the mask with the `loc` method to filter the columns:

```
positive_mask = pivot_data_credit.iloc[-1, :] > 0
positive_clients = pivot_data_credit.loc[:, positive_mask]
non_positive_clients = pivot_data_credit.loc[:, ~positive_mask]
```